# Gradle says my java installation is in the wrong place, despite it finds the correct folder

Tags: java, windows, gradle, windows-10

I'm not sure why, but whenver I run the command `./gradlew setDecompWorkspace`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I've added the JAVA_HOME variable under my System Environment Variables as this: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\`, my system path contains this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`

Comment: This sounds like your command shell hasn't picked up the System Environment Variables setting yet.  Try restarting your command shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the Directory C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin

Change the JAVA_HOME to C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_191 and include the
JAVA_HOME\bin in your path.

JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
path= C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;

Comment: Java home: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`



Path: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AOMEI Backupper;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;`

Comment: Are  you using any other Java version/patch?. what is the command java -version is showing ?

Comment: It gives me this: java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode) The strangest thing is that when I run the commands within IntelliJ, it works perfectly.

Comment: Try running the Gradle task with following command line parameter

                                                                                                                 gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/path_to_Jdk

Comment: I literally can't run any command in gradle because that error keeps coming up